# Are rubber grommets OK for junction box?

Tags: electrical, junction-box

I'm looking at options for lighting my basement workshop.  I really like these "canless" ones that would mount in the suspended ceiling.  Interestingly, some come with junction boxes, but MANY do not--they just have the driver.  I have no problem putting the driver in a junction box, but I need to seal the opening where the low voltage DC wire comes out (and goes to the light).  For low voltage electronics, I would use a rubber grommet for this (with a slit in it because of the connector on the wire).  Is this material OK (code compliant)?  If not, what do you use?

To be clear, I'm asking about the *material*, not the clamping capabilities of the grommet.  If you think the low voltage wire needs clamping, we can discuss, but that wire is already attached/clamped to the driver box.

Here's a pic of one of these lights:
[image]

Comment: The light in the photo is sealed so it does not need a box, but i can not tell how the power transformer is supposed to connect to the power source. Can you provide a link to the spec sheet for the light in question ? It is unclear how you would be using the rubber grommet. More detail is needed. Why not just use a normal junction box clamp ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure 120V connections/splices need to be done inside a box.  That driver's (you called it a transformer) inputs are 120V (see the two wires at the other end).  Thus, the box is for the driver, not for the light.  The DC wire is going to be pretty small--kinda like lamp wire.  "Normal" junction box clamps are for nm cable.

Comment: I don't want to have the driver outside the box because it's another thing I have to mount & protect.  Once inside the box, there will be two sets of wires:  the 14/2 nm cable for the 120V input and the 12V DC output that goes to the light.  The DC wire is going to be pretty small--kinda like lamp wire.  "Normal" junction box clamps are for nm cable.  There are no instructions for these.

Comment: "**Normal" junction box clamps are for nm cable**" Correct, the wire, *whatever kind it may be*,  is run into the box and secured with a clamp and the wire connections are made inside the box with wire nuts. The DC wire going into the driver inside the box could be wrapped with  thicker electrical tape until it is thick enough for the clamp to secure,  or use the grommet but the grommet needs to be clamped. Wires entering or exiting junction boxes need to be secured.

Comment: Interesting.  I wasn't expecting this as an answer because, in my admittedly limited knowledge, I didn't think the NEC concerned itself with low voltage wiring.  I was really concerned about the proper way to cover a knockout hole in the box (fire retardance, for example, hence my question about rubber).  I'm really not being argumentative, but I have questions...doesn't a grommet act as a clamp?   The NEC code allows for wraps of tape to make a wire fit an nm clamp?  And finally, some newer plastic boxes lack clamps and the info I have on them says to secure the wire close to the entrance.

Comment: a gromet acts as a shield ... it prevents wire from touching sharp edges

Comment: The wire needs securing because it spliced together in the box with just wire nuts so it could potentially be pulled apart. Clamp it in the box or staple to a joist or stud near the box. Both work.

Comment: I'm not sure the low voltage wire to the actual light requires clamping.  It is NOT spliced (the spliced wires are the 120V "inputs" to the light).  And, it's attached/clamped to the box via a plastic grommet.  Interestingly, everyone has focused on the clamping, but that wasn't my concern.  My question is really about the material (rubber).  Is it adequate?  I'll modify my question with this additional detail.  Thanks.

Comment: Clarification:  when I said the low voltage wire is attached to the box, I was referring to the box of the driver (not the junction box I want to put the driver in).